# Does Chrome-desktop have built-in "disable all flash" feature?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, desktop-computer

For various reasons[1], I wish to use Chrome-desktop but without the Flash plugin.

**Does Chrome-desktop have built-in (i.e. without a plugin/add-on/etc) "disable all flash" feature? or a "only play if I click on the flash element" feature?**

[1] some of the reasons for wanting to disable all flash in Chrome are: crashes many times per day; seems to use an excessive amount of resources; has many websites that play audio/video automatically when I don't want them to; causes the browser to stop or slow-down mouse/keyboard response times, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To enable click-to-play for all plugins, including Flash:

1. Click the *Menu* button ([image: Chrome's Menu button]) → *Settings*
2. Scroll down and click *Show advanced settings*
3. Under the *Privacy* header click *Content settings...*
4. Under *Plugins* section select *Let me choose when to run plugin content*

All plugin-based elements will look like this:

[image: Plugin placeholder]

To run such plugin you have to right-click that placeholder and select *Run plugin*.

#### To disable Flash completely, but leave other plugins enabled:

1. Navigate to `chrome://plugins` (copy-paste it into the address bar, it's a special link)
2. Find *Adobe Flash Player* on the list
3. Click *Disable*

Comment: Additionally! right under the "Let me choose when to run plugin content" there is a "Manage Exceptions" button. You can give exceptions to allow flash to run without your need to right-click and select "Run Plugin". --> So this solution gives you the best of both worlds (no Flash by default... but flash when if/when you need/want Flash).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it does not, although you can disable all plugins.